# "Compile error: else without if"

Tags: vba, excel, math

I have VBA macro with error which makes no sense (I have had problem before and see the IF statement clearly). Error message:

> Compile error: Else without If

Code (developing demonstration of Intermediate Value Theorem):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Function1()
Dim Polynomial As String
Dim Sign
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Degree
Dim Coefficient

While Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value <> "" '+1 because top row occupied by column A, column B titles. If cell is empty stop.
MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
Degree = Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value 'A2
Coefficient = Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value 'B2
If (Coefficient < 0) Then Sign = " - " ' if coefficient negative
    Else: If Coefficient > 0 Then Sign = " + " ' if coefficient positive
End If
Polynomial = Polynomial & " " & Coefficient & "x^" & Degree 'concatenation string, list polynomial.
counter = 1
counter = counter + 1
Wend
' Finally:
MsgBox poly
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow nevermind. I think you need `elseif`

Comment: else: if is *way* different than elseif which may be what you're after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this:

```
If (Coefficient < 0) Then 
    Sign = " - " ' if coefficient negative
Else
    If Coefficient > 0 Then Sign = " + " ' if coefficient positive
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a new line after Then. Otherwise the if statement is automatically closed at the end of the line. And VBA complains that there is no open if block when it sees the Else.